# Adding missing rows and filling them with zeros in pandas python dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have 2 dataframes That I'm trying to combine so I used the stackoverflow example with some modifications to demonstrate how they look:

Dataframe1:

| left | center | right |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | 0.1 | Tee |
| b | 0.2 | The |
| c | 0.1 | Three |
| d | 0.3 | ee |

Dataframe2:

| left | center |
| --- | --- |
| a | 0.4 |
| c | 0.7 |
| b | 0.5 |

Looking for:

| left | center | center2 | right |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | 0.1 | 0.4 | Tee |
| b | 0.2 | 0.5 | The |
| c | 0.1 | 0.7 | Three |
| d | 0.3 | 0 | ee |

So essentially dataframe 2 is missing some rows and the index/order of the column that I want to join them on is different.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```py
out = (
    df1.merge(df2, on="left", how="outer")
    .rename(columns={"center_x": "center", "center_y": "center2"})
    .fillna(0)
)
print(out)
```

Prints:

```
  left  center  right  center2
0    a     0.1    Tee      0.4
1    b     0.2    The      0.5
2    c     0.1  Three      0.7
3    d     0.3     ee      0.0
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'left' : ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'],
                    'center' : [0.1, 0.2, 0.1, 0.3],
                    'right' : ['Tee', 'The', 'Three','ee']})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'left' : ['a', 'c', 'b'],
                    'center' : [0.4, 0.7, 0.5]})

r = df1.merge(df2, how='outer',on='left').fillna(0)[['left', 'center_x', 'center_y', 'right']]
r.columns = ['left', 'center_1', 'center_2', 'right']

print(r)
```

```
  left  center_1  center_2  right
0    a       0.1       0.4    Tee
1    b       0.2       0.5    The
2    c       0.1       0.7  Three
3    d       0.3       0.0     ee
```